# Reverse engineer .xbap file

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

I am really stuck! I need the source code for a WPF application. The only file I have available is the .xbap file of the application. How can I use this to get the source code? I have looked into using tools like .Net Reflector, ILSpy and dotPeek, however they only support .xap file and NOT .xbap. Please help!!

Comment: I wonder who's application it is

Comment: Ask the author of the application for providing source code so you won't need to decompile/reverse engineer it.

Comment: The author of the application left the company and doesn't have source code any more. So unfortunately the only option I'm left with is reverse engineering.

Comment: Your company should learn a valuable lesson and start using source control.